# Any program that calculates the throughput from the output of tcpdump?

Tags: networking, tcp, benchmarking, throughput, tcptrace

I am currently using tcptrace but am observing some ridiculous throughputs on a test that I'm running. I am pretty sure something is wrong with the way I am testing but before spending any more time is there any other program I can use to verify this?

**EDIT**: This is for a router simulator that I am running locally on my system that generates a tcpdump output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ttcp`](http://www.pcausa.com/Utilities/pcattcp.htm) to measure the TCP performance between two systems.